# Preventing UI from freezing due to ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

The commented out code at https://github.com/DjangoCoder/DjangoGUI/blob/master/templates/base.html on lines 192, 193, 196, 197, 199, and 205 was freezing the UI up. I could barely use my text editor. I want to uncomment those lines. Is there a way to do so without freezing the UI? The site is at

```
http://198.144.178.112:8000
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set async to true. That's the purpose of the async parameter is to allow for this to happen in the background while the browser continues on with the rest of the code.

Edit: Sorry, here's more information.

Starting at line 173, you should change the async parameter in the initialization of the ajax function to true. Like this:

```
function testConnection() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/",
        cache: false,
        async : true,
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#errorbar').css({'height': ($('#header').height()) + 'px'}).show();
        },
        success: function(html){
            $('#errorbar').hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It would have been nice if you said how to set async to true. I'm Googling it now.

Comment: Well, you first search for the only line in your code that contains the word "async", and then you change `false` to `true`.